# Drools - Execute specific rule-flow group?

Tags: drools

In my project i want Drools ( version 5.5.0.final) to execute specific rule flow group.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ruleflow. I tried it with Java AgendaFilters but the API is limited. Create a flow diagram that has your ruleflow-group node and start as process.